# How do I assign random cluster labels to each entry in a dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I'm builidng a k_means algorithm from scratch without the use of ML libraries. The first step of the k_means algorithm is to initialize k random centroids by assigning k random labels to each data point. How do I assign random cluster labels to each entry in a dataset?

```
DEFAULT_CENTROIDS = np.array([[5.664705882352942, 3.0352941176470587, 3.3352941176470585, 1.0176470588235293],
                              [5.446153846153847, 3.2538461538461543, 2.9538461538461536, 0.8846153846153846],
                              [5.906666666666667, 2.933333333333333, 4.1000000000000005, 1.3866666666666667],
                              [5.992307692307692, 3.0230769230769234, 4.076923076923077, 1.3461538461538463],
                              [5.747619047619048, 3.0714285714285716, 3.6238095238095243, 1.1380952380952383],
                              [6.161538461538462, 3.030769230769231, 4.484615384615385, 1.5307692307692309],
                              [6.294117647058823, 2.9764705882352938, 4.494117647058823, 1.4],
                              [5.853846153846154, 3.215384615384615, 3.730769230769231, 1.2076923076923078],
                              [5.52857142857143, 3.142857142857143, 3.107142857142857, 1.007142857142857],
                              [5.828571428571429, 2.9357142857142855, 3.664285714285714, 1.1]])

def get_closest(data_point: np.ndarray, centroids: np.ndarray):
    """
    Takes a data_point and a nd.array of multiple centroids and returns the index of the centroid closest to data_point
    by computing the euclidean distance for each centroid and picking the closest.
    """
    N = centroids.shape[0]
    dist = np.empty(N)
    for i, c in enumerate(centroids): 
        dist[i] = np.linalg.norm(c - data_point)
    index_min = np.argmin(dist)
    return index_min

def k_means(data: np.ndarray, k:int=3, n_iter:int=500, random_initialization=False) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, int]:
    """
    :param data: your data, a numpy array with shape (n_entries, n_features)
    :param k: The number of clusters to compute
    :param n_iter: The maximal numnber of iterations
    :param random_initialization: If False, DEFAULT_CENTROIDS are used as the centroids of the first iteration.

    :return: A tuple (cluster_indices: A numpy array of cluster_indices,
                      n_iterations: the number of iterations it took until the algorithm terminated)
    """
    # Initialize the algorithm by assigning random cluster labels to each entry in your dataset
    centroids = DEFAULT_CENTROIDS[random.sample(range(len(DEFAULT_CENTROIDS)), k)]
    labels = np.array([np.argmin([(el - c) ** 2 for c in centroids]) for el in data])
    clustering = []
    for k in range(k):
        clustering.append(data[labels == k])

    # Implement K-Means with a while loop, which terminates either if the centroids don't move anymore, or
    # if the number of iterations exceeds n_iter
    counter = 0
    while counter < n_iter:
        # Compute the new centroids, if random_initialization is false use DEFAULT_CENTROIDS in the first iteration
        # if you use DEFAULT_CENTROIDS, make sure to only pick the k first entries from them.


        # Update the cluster labels using get_closest


        # if the centroids didn't move, exit the while loop
        pass

    # return the final cluster labels and the number of iterations it took
    return clustering, counter
```

Essentially, what does `clustering` get set to without additional libraries? I tried using `clustering = (DEFAULT_CENTROIDS.sample(n=3))` but that obviously is not a solution.

EDIT1:

```
while counter < n_iter:
    # Compute the new centroids, if random_initialization is false use DEFAULT_CENTROIDS in the first iteration
    # if you use DEFAULT_CENTROIDS, make sure to only pick the k first entries from them.
    if random_initialization is False and counter == 0:
        centroids = DEFAULT_CENTROIDS[random.sample(range(len(DEFAULT_CENTROIDS)), k)]

    # Update the cluster labels using get_closest
    labels = np.array([get_closest(el, centroids) for el in data_np])
    clustering = []
    for i in range(k):
        clustering.append(np.where(labels == i)[0])
            
    counter += 1
        
    new_centroids = np.zeros_like(centroids)
    for i in range(k):
        if len(clustering[i]) > 0:
            new_centroids[i] = data_np[clustering[i]].mean(axis=0)
        else:
            new_centroids[i] = (centroids[i])

    # if the centroids didn't move, exit the while loo
    if clustering is not None and (centroids != new_centroids).sum() == 0:
        break    
    else:
        centroids = new_centroids
    pass

    # return the final cluster labels and the number of iterations it took
    return clustering, counter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I'd create a bi-dimensional array, which will contain the clusters computed at every iteration. You also need to maintain another array that contains the centroid.

```
# Select k centroids from the default one
centroids = DEFAULT_CENTROIDS[random.sample(range(len(DEFAULT_CENTROIDS)), k)]

# Select all the point nearest to every centroid
labels = np.array([np.argmin([np.sum((el - c) ** 2) for c in centroids]) for el in data])

# Create a list, which will contains k sub-list, defining a cluster for every centroid
clustering = []
for i in range(k):
    clustering.append(data[labels == i])
```

Now you need to update the centroids, and repeat this set of operations until you reach your criteria.

EDIT:

We can adapt this to your code using something like:

```
n_iter = 500
random_initialization = True
counter = 0
clustering = None
while counter < n_iter:
    # Compute the new centroids, if random_initialization is false use DEFAULT_CENTROIDS in the first iteration
    # if you use DEFAULT_CENTROIDS, make sure to only pick the k first entries from them.
    if random_initialization is False and counter == 0:
        centroids = DEFAULT_CENTROIDS[random.sample(range(len(DEFAULT_CENTROIDS)), k)]

    # Update the cluster labels using get_closest
    labels = np.array([get_closest(el, centroids) for el in data])

    clustering = []
    for i in range(k):
        clustering.append(np.where(labels == i)[0])

    counter += 1

    new_centroids = np.zeros_like(centroids)
    for i in range(k):
        if len(clustering[i]) > 0:
            new_centroids[i] = data[clustering[i]].mean(axis=0)
        else:
            new_centroids[i] = (centroids[i])

    # if the centroids didn't move, exit the while loop
    if clustering is not None and (centroids == new_centroids).sum() == 0:
        break
    else:
        centroids = new_centroids
```

Comment: In the while loop, how do I update the labels using the `get_closest()` function? Also, how will I know if the centroids didn't move since the previous iteration? See edit for my current while loop

Comment: What is `CENTROIDS` that you're referring to? Did you mean `DEFAULT_CENTROIDS`?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit to fix it